# Is there a way to store the whole build.xml file within Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, ant, continuous-integration, salesforce, build.xml

Current Setup: Ant deployments to salesforce using Jenkins for CI. Pulls from BitBucket repository with paramaterized build.xml stored in the repo. The build properties are set individually for each job in Jenkins.

The Problem: Build properties could be modified if someone changes the build.xml to not reference the variables set in Jenkins. Developers have the ability to change the testlevel, which we would like to prevent. Also, if we ever need to modify the build.xml, we don't want to have to cascade the changes across all of our branches.

Is there a way to remove the build.xml file entirely from the repo and store everything in Jenkins?

Comment: You should try looking into jenkins pipeline scripts

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the Config File Provider plugin:

https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Config+File+Provider+Plugin

I have only played with it a little, but I think it will do exactly what you want. You will just have to copy the file in to the workspace before you run your build.